# Compound primary keys with Dexie.js (IndexedDB) as in SQL?

Tags: typescript, indexeddb

How can I create a compound key (primary key) which consists of several values, for example 'id' and 'date'?

For example with SQL:

```
PRIMARY KEY (name, date)
```

So far I have always created a separate, actually useless, primary key (typescript):

```
export class Database extends Dexie {
item: Dexie.Table<IItem, number>;

constructor() {
    super('db');
    this.version(1).stores({
        items: '++id, name, date, description, value'
    });

    this.items = this.table('items');
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://dexie.org/docs/Compound-Index#compound-primary-key), you can define a compound primary key for tables using the same square bracket syntax you'd use for defining compound keys for an index:

```
db.version(1).stores({
  items: '[name+date]'
});
```

This will result in an IndexedDB table with `Key (Key path: ["name", "date"])`

---

The Dexie TypeScript definition of the `Table` interface types the `Key` generic as `any`:

```
interface Table<T=any,Key=any> extends _Table<T,Key> {}
```

Allowing you to pass an array of types in as the `Key` for your `Table` declaration:

```
Dexie.Table<IItem, [string, Date]>;
```

---

You can query on the compound PK by passing your `name` and `date` as an array of values to the `get` function in the same order used to define the compound PK, `[name+date]`:

```
db.items.get([anItemName, aDate])
```

---

Below is a working example.

For reference, the IndexedDB key path that the example is matching against looks like this:

```
["widget", Sat Dec 12 2020 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)]
```

and the resulting console log looks like this:

```
{name: "widget", date: "2020-12-12T14:00:00.000Z", description: "widget_2", value: 20}
```

---

```
import Dexie from "dexie";

interface IItem {
  name?: string;
  date?: Date;
  description?: string;
  value?: number;
}

class ItemDatabase extends Dexie {
  items: Dexie.Table<IItem, [string, Date]>; // <<<

  constructor() {
    super("SO_64210806");
    this.version(1).stores({
      items: "[name+date]" // <<<
    });
  }
}

(async () => {
  const db = new ItemDatabase();

  await db.items.bulkPut([
    {
      name: "widget",
      date: new Date("2020-12-11T13:00:00.000Z"),
      description: "widget_1",
      value: 10
    },
    {
      name: "widget",
      date: new Date("2020-12-12T14:00:00.000Z"),
      description: "widget_2",
      value: 20
    }
  ]);

  const w2 = await db.items.get(["widget", new Date("2020-12-12T14:00:00.000Z")]); // <<<

  console.log(w2);
})();
```